# Changing serVis graphic text encoding

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, lda

I'm using `R`'s `LDAvis` package to visualize Gibbs sampling result of some East Asian texts (e.g., simplified Chinese and Japanese), but the viewer returns something like below. How do I change the encoding (UTF-8, I believe) to proper display East Asian texts on the left vertical axis?
I was told that using `writeLines()` command should do the trick, but don't know how to.

[image]